# Call method multiple time

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a fake data.txt file for testing. I need to create min 2000 data
I need to call content() 2000+ time. how do I do that

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try{
            // Create new file
            String content = content()+content();

           String path="/Users/raianazaman/Desktop/DataBase/Sample.txt";
           File file = new File(path);

           if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write(content);// Write in file
            bw.close();// Close connection
        }
```

Comment: if you want to repeat a statement many times you can use for loop ex: 
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++) content();
This calls content method 2000 times.

Comment: is the question really just "how to repeat an action a number of times"? With loops https://www.baeldung.com/java-loops

Comment: So here is the this when i add "for(int i=0;i<2000;i++) content(); " it create the same date. but when i write it like content()+content()+content(); it genarate random data

Comment: `StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder(); for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {contentBuilder.append(content()); } String content = contentBuilder.toString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {

      String path = "/Users/raianazaman/Desktop/DataBase/Sample.txt";
      File file = new File(path);

      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
      }

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        bw.write(content());// Write in file
      }
      bw.close();// Close connection
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: So here is the this when i add "for(int i=0;i<2000;i++) content(); " it create the same date. but when i write it like content()+content()+content(); it genarate random data. i need different data every time